# Python permission error preventing script from running

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run a Python script, however, once i try to run this script, i am shown a 'PermissionError: [Errno 13]' message and i'm not sure why this is happening.

I have tried looking here for an answer but to no prevail, i have found nothing which is helping me. Below is the code i am trying to run -

```
import os
import pandas


def summarise(indir, outfile):
    os.chdir(indir)
    filelist = ".txt"
    dflist = []
    colnames = ["Units", "Dealer Price", "Revenue", "End Consumer Country"],
    for filename in filelist:
        print(filename)
        df = pandas.read_csv('SYB_M_20171001_20171031.txt', header=None, 
    encoding='utf-8', sep='\t', skiprows=3)
        dflist.append(df)
        df['Revenue'] = df[11] * df[13]
        df = df.groupby([19, 21]).sum()
        df = df[['Revenue', 11]]
        df.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
        dflist.append(df)
        concatDF.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
        concatDF.columns = colnames


summarise(r"O:\James Upson\Soundtrack Your Brand", 
          r"O:\James Upson\Soundtrack Your Brand Formatted")
```

Here is an SQL query of the function i am trying to create -

```
SELECT SUM(Units*Dealer_Price)
SUM(Units)
Consumer_Country,
Currency Code
FROM Sales File
GROUP BY Consumer_Country, Currency_Code
```

The results of this script should be a five column csv file which will allow me to see the Units of each territory (country), a dealer price associated to each territory, a revenue column showing the output of multiplying the units by the dealer price, and the consumer country and currency code for the territory.

```
11 Units Column
13 Dealer Price Column
19 End Consumer Country Column
21 Currency Code Columns
```

Here is the error message i am seeing

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PogUq.png)

I am pretty sure that my code can be tweaked/made better/fixed so any help on this i would greatly appreciate it :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post more of your stack traceback?  Which line is giving the error?

Comment: What are the permissions of directories "Soundtrack Your Brand" and "Soundtrack Your Brand Formatted"?

Comment: @Sheldon it is a shared network drive

Comment: Check that you can see the directory from your python console. os.path.isdir(r"O:\James Upson\Soundtrack Your Brand")

Comment: @emmet02 Getting an error saying name 'os' is not defined

Comment: import os first...

Comment: @emmet02 Apologies. Returning True now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the file is open by you or someone else on the shared drive (likely someone else).  Python is not able to get a lock on the file.  Change the filename and see if you are able to write to a different file in the same location.

Writing to shared drives can be tricky as the file lock can be open for an extended amount of time if the person who opened the file doesn't correctly release the lock on it.

Comment: Same error unfortunately. I have changed the file name and created to new folders (input and output) in the same location @Luke Brady

Comment: Are you running the code through Python Idle or through command prompt?

Try opening a command prompt window - but run as Administrator.  Change to the directory you are running your script from.  Then "Python my_script.py".  See if that fixes the permission issue.

Comment: Hi Luke, sorry i'm very new to working with Python and everything so sorry to be a pain. I've been trying to run the script in Pycharm. I have got the command prompt up open in administrator mode, would you be able to provide me with the code to change the directory? Sorry once again

Comment: cd C:\Python34

or

cd C:\path\to\my\directory\where\my\script\is

Comment: Okay, i have run this and i think it has accepted this as no error messages were shown, however i am still receiving the same error message.

Comment: Can you write the file locally?  To the same directory the script is in?

Comment: I'm trying to run the script from the command prompt but it doesn't seem to be working still